# Imaginary part of a fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the imaginary part of this function?
$$\displaystyle\frac{-2\mu(x)-2\mu(iy)}{x^{2}+2xiy-y^{2}+b^{2}}$$

I need just the imaginary part for the equation of streamlines in a fluids question but I don't know how to get it as there is an i in the denominator.

Comment: Rationalizing the denominator by multiplying with the conjugate would work.  Are both $\mu(x)$ and $\mu(iy)$ real?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Assuming $\mu$ is a real function and $b^2\in \Bbb R$, multiply by $\displaystyle 1=\frac{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try computing

$$\frac{-2\mu(x)-2\mu(iy)}{x^{2}+2xiy-y^{2}+b^{2}}\cdot \frac{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}$$

$$ = \frac {-2\mu(x)-2\mu(iy)}{(x^2 - y^2 + b^2) + 2xyi} \cdot \;\frac{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}{(x^2-y^2+b^2)-2xyi}$$

Comment: Then we multiply the conjugates in the denominator, which rids us of $i$ in the denominator.